# What kind of creature was the "God" in Star Trek V: The Final Frontier?

Tags: star-trek, the-final-frontier

In *[Star Trek V: The Final Frontier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_V:_The_Final_Frontier)*, the *Enterprise* goes to a planet where they find a creature that claims to be God.

What kind of creature was that?

Does that species show up in any other Star Trek show?

Is it related to the Cytherian that appears in the *Star Trek TNG* episode, *[The Nth Degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nth_Degree_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation))*?

Comment: More importantly, why does he need a spaceship?

Comment: @Valorum - Because it will allow him to pass through the barrier.  Which may or may not have been made by the Q.

Comment: @Xavon_Wrentaile - OK then, why would the Q make such a crappy barrier?

Comment: Why do you think the creature would be related to Cytherians?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I wondered if the creature was related to the Cytherians because they're both from the center of the galaxy, both have enormous powers, and both have enormous amounts of knowledge.

Comment: @Valorum - Arrogance, laziness, underestimating other species.  Take your pick.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Canonically we know only what was shown during the course of *Star Trek V: The Final Frontier*, and nothing more. The being in question was a powerful entity capable of manipulating and deceiving others, but no other information about its origins are shown. There is no indication that it is directly related to any of the other "god-like" beings encountered over the course of the subsequent series.

Non-canonically, according to the novel *Q-strike* by Greg Cox, the entity in question was a being known as "[The One](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_One)" and was brought into the universe by Q and one of his associates, along with [Gorgan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Gorgan) and the [Beta XII-A Entity](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Beta_XII-A_entity). The Q continuum banished The One beyond the galactic barrier after the creature committed various atrocities.

Comment: I could have sworn that Q only helped Zero come through Guardian of Forever; Zero brought all the others more or less on his own.  That said, I am 100% sure that Zero was exiled from the Milky Way and kept out by the Galactic Barrier (and was too slow to travel anywhere else), and The One was sealed on a lifeless planetoid in a separate barrier near the core of the Milky Way...